# How to get MessageBox with multiple textboxes

Tags: extjs

I notice that MessageBox.prompt object does not have an option to display multiple prompts and ask for more than one values.

```
 97                           var dlg = Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'Enter value for:', function(btn, text){
 98                             if (btn == 'ok'){
 99                               console.log('Dude! ' + dlg);// process text value and close...
100                             }
```

Is there a way I can get multiple prompts for ExtJS MessageBox prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom dialog box with textboxes in it.